# How do you check if all the contents in the array are the same? Using swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array thats constantly updating. How do i check if all the contents are the same? For Ex.

```
var Array:[String] = ["1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2"]

if //all array contents are equal to 1 {

println("Array = 1")

}
```

thanks

Comment: I dont know what to try? Any Suggestions?

Comment: the title doesn't match the question Im afraid

Comment: You need to try to solve the problem for yourself before asking for help on SO. Most people on here don't want to do your homework for you, especially if you haven't even shown any effort to solve the problem yourself. Try reading the documentation

Comment: I have looked for a solution, but i can't find one. can you help me?

Comment: what do you want, the question in the title or the question in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution would be to use sets

```
//var set = NSSet(array: [2,3,3,2,1])
var set = NSSet(array: [1,1,1,1,1])

if set.count == 1 {
    println("All the same")
}
```

Comment: thats why I am asking what op wants -- the title doesn't match his code

Comment: actually in XCode 6.3 Sets will be native to Swift so you won't need to use NSSet anymore directly just Set.

Comment: yeah it is, that's why I said "will" not "is" :)

Answer (score 0):

## for the title question: "check if all elements are equal"

```
    //let array = ["1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2"]
    let array = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]

    //just check if all elements *equal*
    let set = NSSet(array: array)
    if set.count == 1 {
        println("all elements equal")
    }
```

## for the code question: check if elements are equal to X

```
    //just check if all elements are equal to X
    let set = NSSet(array: array)
    if(set.count == 1) {
        let myObj = set.anyObject() as String!
        let equalTo = "1"
        if  myObj == equalTo {
            println("all elements equal 1")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func allEquals() -> Bool {
       return self.allSatisfy { $0 == self.first }
   }
}
```

Then use it in your array:

```
yourArray.allEquals()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is just one example, just to show one way to do it:

```
var myArray = ["1","1","2","1"]

func checkOut(array: [String]) -> Bool {
var number = 0

for index in 0..<array.count {
    if array[index] == "1" {
        number++
    }
}

if number == array.count {
    return true }
else {
    return false }
}

checkOut(myArray)
```

Comment: a very complicated one :)